# Using Android source in Eclipse: 9 build path entries are missing?

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation, android-source, rom

I loaded the Android source code into Eclipse. Now I have the following error:

> 9 build path entries are missing.

I tried cleaning it, refreshing it and deleting and re-importing the project.

For instance it tries to get this folder:

```
packages/apps/Phone/src
```

But that is empty. Should I remove it? If I remove it then other files start complaining.

I did:

- `repo sync`
- `. build/envsetup.sh`
- `lunch aosp_arm-eng`
- `make -j32`

Resulting in an output in:

> out/target/product/generic.

Before importing it to Eclipse, so everything must be there to be able to actually create the image. I could also use the `emulator` command and run the built image.

I followed the official tutorial [here](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html).

**Edit**

Some more examples that are empty:

> frameworks/base/icu4j/java
>
> frameworks/ex/photoviewer/src
>
> frameworks/support/renderscript/v8/java/src
>
> out/target/common/obj/APPS/ApiDemos_intermediates/src/src
>
> out/target/common/obj/APPS/Phone_intermediates/src/src
>
> out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-common-carousel_intermediates/src/renderscript/src
>
> out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/NfcLogTags_intermediates/src/src
>
> packages/providers/DrmProvider/src

Comment: did you use the eclipse project setup from [development/ide/eclipse](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/ide/eclipse/)?

Comment: @zapl Yes I did copy the .classpath as described at [this](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) site. Check **Basic setup** second quote. Do I need to add more? Checking the readme it says something with C++ files?

Comment: *"Now edit that copy of .classpath, if necessary."* If those `out` directories don't exist (they are result of `make`) you'll have to adjust paths / remove ones that are not used. Eclipse project is often broken in some places but that does not matter too much since `make` does not care. (A clean in eclipse might even interfere with `make`)

Comment: @zapl Aha I see, I will try this when I get my hands free. Thanks!

Comment: @zapl It worked, but now I face another problem. I am now missing files. For instance in `com.android.calendar.GeneralPreferences` I miss the class `OnTimeZoneSetListener`. Googling on the class does not help.

Comment: Ok I think I know the error, I did not import the other folders. I did the deletion on the folders via .classpath but I might have to add them aswell.

Comment: I wrote a new question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514652/importing-android-source-to-eclipse-outdated-classpath).