# Importing Android source to Eclipse: outdated .classpath?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compilation, android-source

I successfully imported the Android source code into Eclipse. Now Eclipse says I am missing files, but I know I have them present on my hard drive.

The .classpath is outdated which I acquired from [this](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) link. Check **Basic setup**, second quote.

I had to remove some `src` files that was outdated and missing from my hard drive. Now I have to find the right ones that are present on my hard drive but missing by Eclipse. Finding and adding them one by one will be a pain.

Is there an updated .classpath file? Or is it some easy way to add all `src` folders missing to the .classpath?

Comment: How many source folders does your project have?

Comment: @TacB0sS I think the Android source code currently has around one hundred or more. Thing is it is very tedious to search for every missing class, find the location and then import that src folder. If you wondered how many src folders was missing I would say maybe around twenty.

Comment: You can remove all the source folders, and then goto the package explorer select all the folders manually with the mouse/pad, right click -> buildpath -> use as source folder...

Comment: @TacB0sS I tried and the package names are not the same. For instance:  `The declared package "com.android.nfc.handover" does not match the expected package "apps.Nfc.src.com.android.nfc.handover"`

Comment: So you actually need to set apps.Nfc.src as a source folder... correct? and a couple of other folders I guess

Comment: @TacB0sS This folder worked fine before I removed all source and imported this one. My .classpath before I removed all does work but there are some missing folders, around 20 or something. This would work if not the package names were distorted.

Comment: sorry but I'll need more hands on to help! can add more data to your question?

Comment: @TacB0sS What I did now is just let Eclipse have the errors.